# What is a replacement for mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');?

Tags: php, encoding

I am looking to replace

```
 mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

with something else, because I do not have the mb module installed and cannot install it. Is there anything? I tried utf8_decode($string), but that didn't work.

This is different from the question listed, because it tries to do the reverse.

I want to take a string, for example, with ä in UTF8 and convert it into &auml; or its HTML entity as &#num;

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Comment: @mister I explained why it is not a duplicate - it tries to do the reverse.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `htmlentities()` ?

Comment: @Pedro because htmlentities doesn't do the conversion for arbitrary UTF-8 characters, but only for entities that have a non-numeric definition. I want to do it for foreign characters that don't have a pre-defined HTML entity.

Comment: @kloop: Understood, check my answer, it may have what you need.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this code snippet converts ***from*** HTML entities ***to*** UTF-8…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have `mb_convert_encoding` you can try using a `preg_replace_callback` to `UCS-4` encode the `string` and then use `bin2hex`, something like:

```
$string = "★ PHP UTF-8 Sucks! ★";
$entity = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
    $char = current($m);
    $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $char);
    return sprintf("&#x%s;", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
}, $string);
echo $entity;
```

---

```
&#x2605; PHP UTF-8 Sucks! &#x2605;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the use of the [MBString Polyfill library](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-mbstring).
This library adds MBString methods even if you do not have the extension installed on your platform.